# RepoDb cannot find mapping configuration

Tags: orm

I'm trying to use RepoDb to query the contents of a table (in an existing Sql Server database), but all my attempts result in an `InvalidOperationException (There are no 'contructor parameter' and/or 'property member' bindings found between the resultset of the data reader and the type 'MyType')`.

The query I'm using looks like the following:

```
    public Task<ICollection<MyType>> GetAllAsync()    
    {
        var result = new List<MyType>();
         
        using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString).EnsureOpen())
        {
            result = (await db.ExecuteQueryAsync<MyType>("select * from mytype")).ToList();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I'm trying to run this via a unit test, similar to the following:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task MyTypeFetcher_returns_all()
    {
        SqlServerBootstrap.Initialize();
         
        var sut = new MyTypeFetcher("connection string");

        var actual = await sut.GetAllAsync();

        Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
    }
```

The Entity I'm trying to map to matches the database table (i.e. class name and table name are the same, property names and table column names also match).

I've also tried:

- putting annotations on the class I am trying to map to (both at the class level and the property level)
- using the ClassMapper to map the class to the db table
- using the FluentMapper to map the entire class (i.e. entity-table, all columns, identity, primary)
- putting all mappings into a static class which holds all mapping and configuration and calling that in the test
- providing mapping information directly in the test via both ClassMapper and FluentMapper

From the error message it seems like RepoDb cannot find the mappings I'm providing.  Unfortunately I have no idea how to go about fixing this.  I've been through the documentation and the sample tutorials, but I haven't been able to find anything of use.  Most of them don't seem to need any mapping configuration (similar to what you would expect when using Dapper).  What am I missing, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Hey @Andrew, would you be able to share the actual class and/or maybe the table here? Have you also check if all the properties of your class is 'Writeable'? The only possible reasons that the properties will be excluded from the compilation is name-inequality or property writeability. The compilation can be found [here](https://github.com/mikependon/RepoDB/blob/91dd309ebc05b5469ea5f97e0a9f366135db1912/RepoDb.Core/RepoDb/Reflection/Compiler/Compiler.cs#L1159).

Comment: Also, would you be able to check if the `PropertyCache.Get<MyType>()`, `FieldCache.Get<MyCache>()` and/or `DbFieldCache.Get(connection, "MyType", null)` returns the equivalent columns/properties?

Comment: By the way, it would be good if you use the actual type when extracting the DB fields like DbFieldCache.Get(connection, ClassMappedNameCache.Get<MyType>(), null) to test the actual calls.

Comment: @MichaelCamaraPendon thanks for the comments here - they gave me enough to figure out what was going on (and as I suspected it was purely my mistake). It turns out this particular model that I was testing on wasn't writeable. To add some context, this is an application where I'm replacing Dapper with RepoDb so I can take advantage of using property handlers. Between this mistake and accidentally overwriting parts of my db configuration, it took me a little while to get going.  After that however it was pretty smooth sailing, with only a couple of minor issues to sort out.

Comment: Glad to hear that.